# Passing abstact classes as parameters as parameter with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

This is my problem:

I have two classes

```
class A
{
A();
virtual void hello() = 0;
}
```

and a second class, that has this class as a parameter in its constructor

```
class B
{
B(const A var);
...
}
```

For class a i can use a trampolin class as described in the docu. If i try to create binds for the second class, i get the following compile error:

```
error: invalid abstract parameter type
```

with the following bind:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(module,m)
{
py::class<A,PyA>(m,"A")
.def(py::init<>());
py::class<B>(m,"B")
.def(py::init<const A>());
}
```

How can i pass an argument like this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

B signature is invalid - abstract classes can't be instantiated and passed by value.

Most likely it should be

```
void B(const A*);
```